# How to add the data to the listview in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I try to add the data to ListView. But I don't know how to add the data to the Listview.

The code of the `DemoActivity` is like the following:

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity
{
    public static ListView StreamID_list;
    private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> StreamIDlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    private static String[][] StreamList = new String[10][2];
    private StreamListAdapter mStreamListAdapter;
    private String[] list = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);


    StreamID_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.StreamID_list);

    mStreamListAdapter = new StreamListAdapter(DemoActivity.this);
    StreamID_list.setAdapter(mStreamListAdapter);

   }

   class HttpServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection
{
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder boundService)
    {
        service = IHttpService.Stub.asInterface((IBinder) boundService);
        Log.d(DemoActivity.TAG, "onServiceConnected() connected");
        Toast.makeText(DemoActivity.this, "Service connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
    {
        service = null;
        Log.d(DemoActivity.TAG, "onServiceDisconnected() disconnected");
        Toast.makeText(DemoActivity.this, "Service disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public class StreamListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater mInflator;
    ArrayList<String> mlist;
    public StreamListAdapter(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = null;
        if(convertView == null){
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.streamid_data, null);
        }

        TextView id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID_text);


        return view;
    }
```

How to add the data to the `listView` and show on the phone ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to set data to your adapter once you have created it, maybe creating a constructor with parameters for your adapter

```
  public StreamListAdapter(ArrayList<String> mlist) {
      this.mlist = mlist;
  }
```

This is sufficient for the first time, after that if you modify your data list you have to call

```
  notifyDataSetChanged();
```

on your adapter;)